# Publish smartphone app as organization

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, apple-developer

I'm working at company A and we're about to publish an app on behalf of company B. We have the code for both Android and iOS but we don't have accounts for Google Play Console or Apple Developer and neither does company B.

We want the publisher name in App Store and Google Play Store to be company B. So this is a two part question:

**App Store:**
I'm aware that you can have an organizational developer account but does this require company B to have their own account as well?

**Google Play Store:**
On this one I am totally lost. I have found no information about creating a Google Play Console account as a organization. Does it require you to have an enterprise account? What does it takes from company B?

I've tried to research this but I might have been searching for the wrong things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to publish On Behalf of Company B then **Company B must have Apple developer account.**

- If you have credentials of the Company B then you don't need to purchase Developer Account for Company B(If you want to avoid two purchase)
- If purchasing two account is not an issue or you don't have credentials to Company B then you can Assign your Company A as Developer in Company B and give rights at your that suits you the best.

I am an iOS developer i can just help you with Apple.

Comment: What credentials from company B do I need (the not so obvious ones)? Do you need company B's Duns-number?

Thanks for the help, I really appriciate it!

Comment: DUNS number is required when you apply for.  Company account. In your case it is required. By credentials I just meant appleid and password.

Comment: I see. Just to be totally clear: the publisher-name that will be shown in App Store is the name of the Organization Account (here company B) or is that something you can change in Xcode/during the publishing process.

(Sorry for being unclear) we handle almost all of company B's tech so we could legally create accounts in their name.

Comment: Publisher name will be Compnay B's name. It will be same for all app that will be from its account. You can't change that from Xcode or from app.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I hope you have a fantastic week!